# Is today a power plant powered by electron-positron pairs annihilation a feasible solution to the energy crisis?

Tags: energy, particle-physics, electricity, antimatter

I came across this article [here](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.102.105001) about a very efficient method with potential industrial applications in the  electric power generation, of producing a large amount of positrons (antimatter).

By scaling up this method a sustainable and efficient electron-positron matter-antimatter reactor could be build powering an electric power plant? This new technology could possible be the solution today for the energy crisis and demand for clean and cheap energy? Especially when nuclear fusion has a long way to go yet.

How feasible is today such an alternative matter-antimatter reactor using electron-positron pairs for the generation of large scale consumer electric power and what are the potential obstacles imposed by the actual physics involved and also technological potential limitations we have today?

Answer (score 6):

You'll get less energy out than it took to create the positrons in the first place. Like hydrogen, this wouldn't be an energy generation. Unlike hydrogen, this wouldn't even be energy storage because hydrogen is stable if you keep it away from oxygen. We have no similar way to store massive amounts of anti-matter, and it would be extremely dangerous, even if we could.

So, no, it isn't feasible for power generation.

Comment: No need for storage. According to the  referenced paper the proposed electron-positrons pairs generation  method  using a gold plate target material from which the pairs are extracted could be used IMHO in combination with other targets forming an array thus this technology could be scaled up. The extracted then pairs could be guided  immediately  to an annihilation chamber and the generated γ-rays used for the production of electric power. The fs ultra short infrared laser pulses power needed for each target described in the article is only 100W.

Comment: The potential yield estimated by the authors of this article is 10E9 s^–1 sr^–1 positrons per target (i.e. 6mm diameter, 0.1mm-3mm thick gold disc). Of course I am not sure if a trigger fs ultra fast pulse infrared laser needed exists today that can deliver 100W continuous laser power? In their experiment they used  a ~100J fs pulse fired every half an hour.

Comment: @Markoul11 The key point is that the energy that is consumed by the laser will be greater than the energy that can be recovered from the products.

Comment: @gandalf61 Yes, that is correct.